# Fold DynamoDB low level interface query result into its original json format

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Recently i had to switch from using high level AWS DynamoDB python boto3 API to the low level one so i could talk to AWS DAX cache engine. Surprisingly biggest pain in the butt using low level API was the format that it uses to present query result. It contains not just the data but also data type indicators being put as dict keys... I came up with short function to deal with that. I'd like to share it here, perhaps someone else may have similar issue and finds it useful. Also i'd like to ask you guys if you could suggest better way of dealing with such conversion.

```
def fold(z):
    """ Fold DynamoDB low level interface query result into its original json format """

    if type(z) == list:
        return [fold(x[y]) if (y := next(iter(x))) in {"M", "L"} else x[y] for x in z]

    elif type(z) == dict:
        return {x: fold(z[x][y]) if (y := next(iter(z[x]))) in {"M", "L"} else z[x][y] for x in z}
```

Here is sample input...

```
{'formats': {'M': {'command_output': {'M': {'show clock': {'S': 'Output...'},
     'show version': {'S': 'Output...'},
     'show ip interfaces brief': {'S': 'Output...'}}}}},
 'device_type': {'M': {'cisco_asa_mc': {'L': [{'S': 'vf1fw1'},
     {'S': 'vf2fw1'},
     {'M': {'t1': {'S': 'to1'}, 't2': {'S': 'to2'}, 't3': {'S': 'to3'}}}]},
   'cisco_switch': {'L': [{'S': 'aklas1'},
     {'S': 'aklds1'},
     {'S': 'ams2as1'},
     {'S': 'asdas1'},
     {'L': [{'S': 'test1'}, {'S': 'test2'}]}]}}},
 'name': {'S': 'labwr1'},
 'type': {'S': 'cisco_router'},
 'timestamp': {'S': '2020-03-07 14:21:11 EDT'}}
```

And sample output...

```
{'formats': {'command_output': {'show clock': 'Output...',
   'show version': 'Output...',
   'show ip interfaces brief': 'Output...'}},
 'device_type': {'cisco_asa_mc': ['vf1fw1',
   'vf2fw1',
   {'t1': 'to1', 't2': 'to2', 't3': 'to3'}],
  'cisco_switch': ['aklas1',
   'aklds1',
   'ams2as1',
   'asdas1',
   ['test1', 'test2']]},
 'name': 'labwr1',
 'type': 'cisco_router',
 'timestamp': '2020-03-07 14:21:11 EDT'}
```

Comment: Just so I am clear, are you using the actual DynamoDB DAX client? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rolling your own solution, consider using the boto3 [`TypeDeserializer`](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/6a6bf486d9dab16b0ac8d3accce07b5178ce8954/boto3/dynamodb/types.py#L234):

```py
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer

serde = TypeDeserializer()
out = {k: serde.deserialize(v) for k, v in your_input.items()}
```

In the same module, you’ll also find a `TypeSerializer` to go the other way.